# Add an ID to :before Pseudo Class

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Is it possible to add a class or ID to the content of your :before pseudo class? I know this doesn't work, but something like:

```
#menu {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
#menu:before {
    class: "just-before-menu";
}
.just-before-menu {
    background: green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: `:before` is a pseudo-element. And no, you can't do this unless you group the selectors themselves.

Comment: Can I select it somehow? Something like:

`#menu span {/*CSS goes here*/}`

Comment: Select it in what?  You just selected it with `#menu:before`.  You can't access these pseudo-elements outside of CSS.

Comment: Also what do you mean by adding a class or ID "to the content"?

Comment: I want to target the `#menu:before` in jquery, so I can display and hide based on other events.

Comment: @ElijahMurray: pseudo-elements cannot be targeted by jquery. If you need to target it, you need to make it a real element (span or something).

Answer (score 2):

> The :before selector inserts content before the content of the selected element(s).
>
> Use the content property to specify the content to insert.

```
#menu:before {
    content: '';
    background: green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp